# I get a load balance error 429 on a particular website

Tags: windows, ubuntu, blocked-services

In particular I get "Load Balancer Error: 429 Someone on your network is abusing this site with automated malicious software" when connecting to torrentz.eu or any mirror site. If I connect via my usual browser, Aurora, I don't get the error but I would like to maximise my anonymity when browsing this or any other site. The fact I can connect using a non-Tor browser suggest a problem in the Tor network or the site itself accepting connections from the Tor network. This only started happening this week and I haven't changed anything on my network. I use 4 different OS's; Windows XP, 7, 8.1 and Ubuntu. I update Tor every time an update is posted. Error occurs on all OS's via Tor. Any suggestions on what is causing this would be appreciated?

Comment: I have the same issue, starting last week and would like an answer to this problem as I cannot connect to these sites through my I.P

Comment: CLEAR YOUR CACHE. restore browser setting. It worked for me.

Comment: I think that those sites have made up some system that limits how many request can come from the same IP in a certain time. When you try to connect to it through Tor the site sees the IP of the exit node of your circuit, that could be in use by lot of other Tor users that might have recently visited those sites. You might try to force the use of another exit node and if you are lucky and found one that has not been used much recently is should work. This assuming those sites are not just cutting out all Tor users.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the site was shut down, so an answer won't help future users. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrentz