# "Load Balancer Error: 429 Someone on your network is abusing this site with automated malicious software

Tags: security, windows

"Load Balancer Error: 429 Someone on your network is abusing this site with automated malicious software" when connecting to torrentz.eu or any mirror site. Recent occurance with no change to prompt the message. Any suggestions on what is causing this would be appreciated?

Comment: I'm sure you're an honest Tor user and wouldn't abuse a web site, so this error reflects the actions of all the other people using Tor who *are* abusing web sites.

Comment: Does this happen when you connect through Tor or without Tor? If it is through Tor, then _'Someone on your network'_ is really _'someone who exits from the same exit as you'_. You could try a different exit. Otherwise, do you run a relay? Some sites block all IPs running relays, even non-exits. (I just tested and I can connect with or without Tor. And I do run a relay on this IP.)

Comment: Jobiwan...happens only when it  connect thru tor.....what do you mean about trying a different exit?

Comment: If they just block traffic from all Tor exits, then tough luck. But maybe someone was actually abusing them from some specific exit(s) and they only blocked that/those IP(s).

Comment: This question is the same as this one: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4042/i-get-a-load-balance-error-429-on-a-particular-website

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the site was shut down, so an answer won't help future users. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrentz